# Swift Scanner works differently in Xcode and Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm trying to extract double value from strings like:

```
"0.01 USD"
```

Problem is it's not working correctly and i can not find example for my case.

My code from Xcode:

```
private func extractDoubleFromTextField(textField: UITextField) -> Double {
    var result : Double = 0.0

    let currentText = textField.text

    print("extracted text: \(currentText!)")

    if (currentText != nil) {
        let scanner = Scanner.localizedScanner(with: currentText!)
        (scanner as AnyObject).scanDouble(&result)
    }

    print("result before return: \(String(format:"%.2f", result))")

    return result
}
```

Output:

```
extracted text: 0.01
result before return: 0.00
```

Doing same code in Playground gives me correct values:

```
var result : Double = 0.0
let currentText = "0.01"

if (currentText != nil) {
let scanner = Scanner.localizedScanner(with: currentText)
    (scanner as AnyObject).scanDouble(&result)
}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
0.01
```

**Update**

Function scanDouble returning true (success) even for case "0.01" -> 0.00

And testing on virtual device giving me correct results:
"0.01" -> 0.01

Comment: 1. Why the use of `(scanner as AnyObject)`? 2. Always check the result of `scanDouble`. It returns a Bool indicating whether it succeeded or not. 3. Run your code in the debugger and see what is really happening in your code.

Comment: 1 - Xcode asked me to do this. 2 - thanks, will try